# Insert big XSLT into Clob column

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, xslt, clob

I have a big XSLT which I have to insert into a Clob column. My problem is that I get an error message when I try to insert the XSLT into the clob column. It says that it exceeds the 4000 character limit. Problem is that I know that CLOBS can contain more than that.. I just cant insert more than that into it.. :/

my insert looks like this:

```
insert into table1 values ('','TK','0','<XSLT HERE>');
```

I just copy the XSLT into the `<XSLT HERE>`.

Surely this is possible to do in some way? any advice?

Comment: Are you getting a database or PL/SQL error? Can you share the actual message and error number with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the character limit from 4000 to 32767 if you use PL/SQL:

```
declare
    v_xslt varchar2(32767) := '<XSLT HERE>';
begin
    insert into table1 values ('','TK','0',v_xslt);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to insert empty_clob() value into your table, then select it for update and operate with it using DBMS_LOB package. See for example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0660__Large-Objects/ReadingandWritingtoaCLOB.htm)